# facebook fb.login two popups

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am having a problem with facebook authentication in facebook Page Tab. I am usin JavaScript SDK FB.login method. I need theese scope: 'email,publish_stream'} permissions. And then I am launching my authentication function I am getting two popups one which asks to login and gives email permition and other requires to allow to post on whall. My question is how to login with only one permission asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer to my question!

- Go to https://developers.facebook.com/apps
- Click on your app.
- Click edit app
- Click Advanced
- Check Enhanced Auth Dialog: Disabled

Thats it. You have one authentication popup.

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the way these days.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/

Here they specify two types of permissions. Basic permissions and extended permissions. publish_stream falls in the second category and that is why you are getting two pages.

This is a new thing they have made to make sure users understand what they are giving access to.

"You can ask for the following extended permissions in the scope parameter of the Auth Dialog.

If you are using the Enhanced Auth Dialog, these permissions are revocable, and are presented on the second page of the Dialog."

This is because of the Enhanced Auth Dialog.

Comment: http://www.facebook.com/pages/testai/192688120807502?sk=app_115995545177771 could you check if it is possible to get only one permission page. Click "ĮKELTI..." to start authentication. Thank you very much.

Comment: According to how the permissions work now it will not be possible to only get one permission page :)