# Facebook api is opening two popups

Tags: jquery, facebook

I am working in facebook api, but what is happening is that when I click **"login with facebook"** it **opens two popups instead of one.**

Its like if **user** is **already logged in facebook**, on clicking the button it **opens a pop up** and in a fraction of seconds **comes back** by **checking session** and my **site works perfect** in that case but **in case if the user is not logged in** , in that case ***two pop ups comes out***, now what happens when the users enters the **credentials correct** and **presses enter** in the popped up window it closes but because of **second (already present) window** my script does not works but any how my **session variable gets saved** with the **userId** *(what actuallyI want)*, **( I know this thing because when I refreshes my website index page after closing the unwanted pop up I go to my profile page normally).**

I referred [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7982358/facebook-fb-login-two-popups) as well to resolve but of no use. please shed some light to open only one popup.

I am using this code as :

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>



<!-- Start of facebook login -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<fb:login-button size="large" id='login'">
      Login with Facebook
</fb:login-button>
<script>
  // initialize the library with the API key
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      try{
        FB.init({
            apiKey      : 'API KEY',
            status      : true, 
            cookie      : true,
            xfbml       : true,
            oauth       : true
        }); 

        FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
            loginHandler(); 
        });
      }catch(error){}
  };  
    function loginHandler(response,fail)
    {
        try{
            if(response && response.authResponse){
                FB.api('/me', function(response,fail) {

                    var email=response.email;
                    var firstName=response.first_name;
                    var lastName=response.last_name;
                    var gender=response.gender;
                    var dob=response.birthday;
                    var remainLogin=$('#remainLogin').val();

                    $('#login').attr("disabled", true);

                    $.ajax({
                        url: "loginViaFacebook",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {email:email,firstName:firstName,lastName:lastName,gender:gender,dob:dob,remainLogin:remainLogin},
                        success: function (data) {

                            if (data.indexOf("true") != -1){ 
                                location.href = 'MainHome.jsp';
                            }
                            else 
                                jAlert('Email not registered ... ','Email not found',ERROR);

                            $('#login').attr("disabled", false);
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                            if(xhr.status==404)//Wrong url
                                jAlert('Check the url','ERROR',ERROR);
                            else if(xhr.status==500)//Exception in server side coding
                                jAlert('Exception in server coding, check your email or try one more time','ERROR',ERROR);
                            else if(xhr.status==408)//timeout
                                jAlert('Server taking time to respond','ERROR',ERROR);
                            else 
                                jAlert('Some error occured ' + thrownError,'ERROR',ERROR);

                            $('#login').attr("disabled", false);
                        },
                        timeout : 5000
                    });

                });
            }
        }catch(error){alert(error);}
    }
    var popUp;
    $('#login').bind('click', function(response) {
        try{
            FB.login(loginHandler, {scope: 'email,user_birthday'});
        }catch(error){}
    });

    $('#logout').bind('click', function() {
        try{
            FB.logout(function(response){});
        }catch(error){}
      });


  </script>


<!-- End of facebook login -->
```

Comment: This question is practically impossible to read.

Comment: Leave it, its 5 years old, that problem is fixed :D

Comment: Stackoverflow is not just for askers to get their answers, but also for other people to find these questions and also solve their problems. I, along with ~600 others, found this page in order to solve our problem. So yeah, I will comment when questions/answers are illegible because it isn't just for _you_, it's for all of us.

Answer (score 0):

you are calling "loginHandler" in "window.fbAsyncInit" as well as on button click, replace this in your fbinit method and try

```
  FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
           loginHandler();

        }             
   });
```